# Chrome API to manipulate dns entries?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dns

Was going through the Chrome documentation and there is a reference to chrome.dns API. (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions#dns) 
However, there is no documentation to support it.

Does anyone know if this is available on Chrome?
Goal is to create an extension that allows the user to add *local host entries* liek for example:

www.mydomain.com points to 127.0.0.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The chrome.dns or chrome.experimental.dns API was deprecated, though it only allowed to to resolve a hostname, not setup a local hosts file.

You should be able to do what you want using onBeforeRequest, though. See this other question: [How can i modify the host header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382813/how-can-i-modify-the-host-header).